# How to know that from which python module class has been imported?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

lets suppose ,
 class **Post** is a subclass of class **Model**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

where class **Model** is imported from **base.py module** from **models** package

So , How can i find from which **module**  , class or  any other name  is imported in my program ? 
Is their any programmatically approach to find  ?

Comment: Each module, class, and class instance, function, object, etc. should have a `__module__` attribute.

Comment: thks Alexander Huszagh .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the **module** property of a class to checkout to which module it belongs.

try:

```
print Model.__module__
```

Comment: thks Caio Tomazelli  :)

Comment: You're welcome!
Check dir(models.Model) to see other properties of you class that may be useful!
Also, check this answer as the accepted one if this has solved your problem!